# Postgresql: Processing Text, Detect out of Alphabetical order rows

Tags: postgresql, text, string-metric

I have some processed text that's in (mostly) alphabetical order, e.g. these are the first word of each paragraph:

- Adelanto
- Agoura Hills
- Alameda
- Albany
- *Old Albany*

  - *New Albany*
- Alhambra
- Aliso Viejo
- Alturas

So each of the words above represents the start of a paragraph e.g.:

> Adelanto,  a city in San Bernardino County, California about 9 miles (14 km) northwest of Victorville in the High Desert portion of the Inland Empire of the Greater Los Angeles Area...

The text can have many paragraphs per entry so that paragraphs not in  alphabetical order are treated as new entries.

So each entry would correspond to a place.

In the Example, O(ld) is after A(lbany) so `Old Albany` is a Entry, but N(ew) is before O(ld), so  `New Albany` a continuation of `Old Albany`.

My question is: Is there something already existing other than just using the  ASCII character difference between the first letter of `Albany` and `Old Albany`/`New Albany` in Postgresql? E.g. ASCII ('A') - ASCII ('O') gives -14.

So do I just use ASCII values on the first characters?  Or is there a more general solution?

Comment: This seems more like a riddle than a question. What is a "character difference" supposed to be and what does it have to do with the rest? What is your goal and what is your question? What is your version of Postgres and what is your table definition (`\d tbl` in psql)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I'm using the ASCII difference between the first letters of the text, comparing to the `previousRow.description` and also `nextRow.description` e.g.

```
ABS (ASCII (substring ( currentRow.description, 1,1 ) )  - 
ASCII ( substring ( previousRow.description, 1 ,1 ) )
```